# Linkedin API - get profile statistics

Tags: statistics, linkedin-api, share

I would like to get API for getting statistical data from my account:

- number of views
- number of likes
- number of reads (article)
- who is watching my posts...

I already have my developers account and get already approved Marketing Developer Platform.

Problems:

- Obviously the Marketing Developer Platform is not enough for permission - r_member_social
- I am not sure if I need r_member_social, because I would not like to read posts - only statistics
- I can't found statistic API

What I would like:

- Witch API to use
- Witch permission I need (scope)
- If I need something more...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not this alters your API permissions or not but I'm pretty sure those statistics are only viewable with a LinkedIn premium membership, so I doubt you can access it with their API.